# How to add content to a tab in Action Bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have some tabs in the Action Bar as in the code below. But I want to add contents like a few buttons and an EditText to each tab. I am not sure how to do this. Can anybody tell me where should I place this. I will be great full to you for any help. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MLkeyboardActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * current tab position.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mlkeyboard);

    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section1)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section2)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3)
            .setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current tab position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_mlkeyboard, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
    // container view.

    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
            tab.getPosition() + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to add contents like a few buttons and an EditText to each tab. I am not sure how to do this.

Put them in the fragment that you are loading in `onTabSelected()`.

Or, modify `onTabSelected()` to do something else, instead of replacing a fragment, to affect your desired changes to your UI.

Comment: Since the tabs have no name how to call them again?

Comment: @user1995307: I have no idea what you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: I think the onTabSelected() in common for all tabs, how to add contents to a particular tab?say tab1

Comment: @user1995307: First, `onTabSelected()` is passed in the `Tab` that was selected. Second, you can supply separate `TabListener` objects per tab, if desired.

Comment: I have created a button named button1 and given onclick=malayalam but it does not work underonTAbSelect                          public void malayalam (View view) {
   TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
   tv.setText("hai");

Comment: @user1995307: Perhaps you should consider learning how to developer simpler Android user interfaces, before embarking upon action bar tabs, as it would appear that you have limited Android development experience. Or, perhaps you should consider using an Android developer support site in a language that is more comfortable for you -- I have several sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. Beyond that, I have no means to help you based on incomplete bits of source code pasted into StackOverflow comments.

Comment: finally my problem solved. The one tutorial helped me I will put it as my answer.If we just look for smaller things how can we learn new things? Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

Also, you could create an OptionCommand and setAction on top of that.

Comment: is it should be given below the setTabListener? The button and Edit text should be in main.xml file?

Comment: You could add it to the main.xml. You would have to change the onTabSelected() method.

Comment: Thank you. But when I put the button in main.xml it will be displayed in all tabs. I want each tab with seperate contents.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial solved my problem. What we have to do is create number of fragments (say FragmentA,B,C )corresponding to each tab and call those fragments using each tabs.The code is avilable for download in the link below
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/create-actionbar-in-tab-navigation-mode.html

```
public class AndroidNavigationTabsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
    tabA.setText("Tab A");
    tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentA>(this, "Tag A", MyFragmentA.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabA);

    Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
    tabB.setText("Tab B");
    tabB.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentB>(this, "Tag B", MyFragmentB.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabB);

    Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
    tabC.setText("Tab C");
    tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentC>(this, "Tag C", MyFragmentC.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabC);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int savedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("SAVED_INDEX");
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedIndex);
    }

}
```